# Number theory prime number conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, rational-numbers

I came up with a theorem that a number $n$is prime if it is not divisible by any prime number $a \le \approx \sqrt{n}$

My proof is that past that set limit any prime number divisible would share a factor less than the same set limit, which should have already been discovered had it existed. Hope that makes sense.

Take for example 29. Approximately its square root is 5. It's not divisible by any primes up to 5. Therefore if it was divisible by say 7, then the corresponding factor i.e $7 \cdot k = 29$ would have to be less than 5. But it was never discovered from 2 upwards which is a logical contradiction.

Is there a way to write this down analytically?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: So you are trying to state that : *every composite number $n$ has a factor $a$ such that $1\lt a\le \sqrt n$* ? Impressive observation  , but unfortunately , it is already a known fact and basis for many prime - searching algorithms .

Comment: I know but his proof was a bit hard to understand

Comment: The good news is that your argument is fine as is (just a little clumsy), and doesn't need to be written down "analytically". Unfortunately, it's not a new observation.

Comment: Wow. I'm always beaten to proofs. But I'm kinda proud. @The Demonix_Hermit you have answered my question

Comment: Strictly speaking, the claim is false for $n=1$.

Comment: Why exactly is that the case

Comment: @NeoPlato First ask yourself : *Is $1$ a prime number or a composite number ?*

Comment: Neither by the formal definitions of both

Comment: The question of what 1 is? Interesting. What was your answer

Comment: Since it is neither prime nor composite , it would be better to handle this case alone . $($Although it is unnecessary as the factors of $1$ are equal to square root $1$ .$)$

Comment: Nice. This is actually my mental algorithm for checking for primes $\le 1000$ when I'm on road trips.

Comment: @NeoPlato If it's any consolation, I believe you were beaten to this one by literally thousands of years...

Comment: The trial division algorithm is based on this conjecture which in fact must be very very old and is very easy to approve by a contradiction-proof. I think we can safely assume that Euklid knew this algorithm, so Steven should be right.

Answer (score 2):

Start by considering two factors of a number $n$ , let them be $a,b$ .

We will prove this using method of contradiction .

Assume $a,b\gt \sqrt n$ .

Then , $$a\times b \gt \sqrt n \times \sqrt n \implies ab\gt n$$

But this contradicts the fact that $ab = n$ . This is because of the incorrect assumption that both $a,b \gt \sqrt n$ holds at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good observation, and it can be proven as follows:

Let $n=ab$, and let $a<b$. Suppose, for sake of contradiction that $a>\sqrt{n}$, then $$n=ab>\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}=n$$ Therefore $a\leq \sqrt{n}$, and so the smallest factor is less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$.

Now if no prime $p<\sqrt{n}$ divides $n$, you can conclude that $n$ cannot be written as $n=ab$, with $a,b$ non-units, which means $n$ is prime.